# Remove recurring-payments using django-merchant off-site processing

Tags: django, paypal, payment, recurring-billing

So I am trying to add payments to my online game using django-merchant with off-site processing. If I understand correctly, is the correct and secure way to proceed for an unsecure web-site (processing payment off-site lets service provire, ie PayPal, take care off all security concerns).

At least using Paypal, I can already process regular payments, and I think I figured out how to start a recurring payment, but I could not find any help about how to proceed to cancel a recurring payment: can I safely use Gateways? or is there any other way, without having to comply on my server with all the mess of regulations which on-site processing requires?

If I sound confused it is because I am, sorry

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

To simplify a complext topic (payment security & regulation) quite a bit, hopefully without dropping any critical bits:

The biggest set of regulations which merchants usually get "hit" with are PCI requirements, which are requirements from card networks on how card information must be handled to protect the integrity of those networks and the accounts of the cardholders.

The simplest way to avoid these requirements is to make sure that "you" (your code, your website, your admins, etc.) absolutely never touch (see, transfer, store) either a card number or a "high value token" (which is something that can be translated to a card number or used to fully substitute for a card number). An encrypted card number is a high value token. A "handle" or "accountid" or whatever they call it from a card processor (e.g. stripe, braintree, cybersource) is a high value token if it can be used to arbitrarily charge that card again (basically to do everything the card number can do).

PayPal email & password (or PIN) are not technically a "high value token" in the eyes of the card network because they give access to a PayPal account, not to a card, but it is just as dangerous (if not moreso) and PayPal's own equivalent of PCI regulations dictate you should never be able to touch that info either. So while a PayPal login isn't subject to PCI, think of it the same.

So the easiest way to avoid that quagmire is to NEVER touch anything like that, and just have money appear in your account. You're allowed to touch the money :-).

But that doesn't allow rebilling/recurring payments/etc. So sometimes that is not enough.

Fortunately, a *limited* token of some sort is not nearly as dangerous and is therefore not subject to the same scrutiny as a "high-value" token. What is a limited token? It is a token that CANNOT be used to arbitrarily charge the source account (and cannot be exchange for, or translated to, the underlying card number).

A limited token *can* be used to charge the account but *only subject to specific conditions*, normally including only payments to a specific merchant (you) and perhaps additional limitations such as total amount of charges and/or a time period.

Some examples:

- Many processors allow you to use a transaction ID to make followup transactions, including rebilling the customer for additional charges. But since the use is limited in this way, holding transaction IDs does not subject you to PCI (or equivalents).
- recurring payment "billing agreements" or "subscription agreements" from PayPal or other payment providers, same deal: multiple payments but limited in nature; no PCI.

In any case: any token which you are allowed to receive you are also allowed to maintain. So if you can set up a recurring payment agreement you are also allowed to store that agreement token so that you can cancel it (and perform whatever other operations that token supports such as rebilling, adjusting terms, etc).

Two other cautions, briefly:

1) it is tempting to say that as long as you have a "token" instead of a card number (or PayPal account credentials) that you are exempt from PCI regulations. This is NOT true! Beware *high-value* tokens that could theoretically be exchanged for card numbers or be used in a fully equivalent fashion. Ensure you have *limited* tokens for your regulatory compliance, and for your safety and your customers' safety. You do NOT want to be the next (mini-) Target card breach source. Black hats are not highly motivated to crack your site if all it contains are tokens that can only be used to extend someone else's subscription to your game. But if you have credit cards... game on.

2) You should still follow best practices for protecting your customers even when PCI doesn't apply. Pay particular attention to two attack vectors:

First, your payment integration. Your customers will probably be entering something sensitive (card number, login, etc) somewhere in that process. Having that happen OFF your site is a great start and helps with PCI... but your business will still explode, and potentially could have legal liability, if your page that redirects to PayPal gets hacked and redirects your customers to a fake PayPal site. Or if you try to get clever and put the PayPal page in an iframe (or other integration mechanism that violates PayPal's requirements), and your page gets hacked with a cross-site scripting attack that captures PayPal logins or card numbers. Etc.

The second attack vector that you should protect against, even if you were never receiving payments, is theft of user account and login information. It's obvious that if you have a database full of credit cards then you are a target. It may be less obvious but any database with passwords is useful to hackers given how often people share passwords across sites. Even without stealing your password file, a poorly-done login page that allows infinite retries can be used to test email/password combinations which can then be tried on other sites! And even any database with user names & email addresses is valuable, because black hats can use this to craft much more convincing "spear phishing" attacks.

In short, the less information you touch (and especially that you store) the less you are a target and the safer everyone is, but security is pretty much always a consideration. So avoid card numbers (and thus PCI), but don't stop there: keep working to protect your customers.

Comment: Thanks, haven't solved my problem yet, but the overview helps :)

Comment: Happy to help with more specifics, but I did not see any specific questions other than avoiding the security mess. Can you clarify what else you need?